# Two-way filter updating on the fly | Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How one can do custom two-way filter for model, updating on the fly in Vue.js.

The following code example from docs works on input blur. But I need it work on keypress.

```
Vue.filter('currencyDisplay', {
  read: function(val) {
    return '$'+val.toFixed(2)
  },
  write: function(val, oldVal) {
    var number = +val.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')
    return isNaN(number) ? 0 : parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))
  }
})
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you expand on this? I have a working JSFiddle using your pasted filter that updates on every single keystroke.  http://jsfiddle.net/b6ubat6k/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter to a Vue data property by creating a computed property with a `get` and `set` method that fire the `read` and `write` methods of the filter, respectively:

```
data() {
  return {
    foo: 0,
  }
},
computed: {
  filteredFoo: {
    get() {
      return Vue.filter('currencyDisplay').read(this.foo);
    },
    set(value) {
      this.foo = Vue.filter('currencyDisplay').write(value);
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/wkyzn72c/)